# How can i get all text input values with same name if they were cloned with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, input, clone

How can i get all text input values from elements with same name if they were cloned with jquery? i want to use in a form using php but i dont know how to store these values into a variable. any help please?

```
<input type="text" name="family-member" placeholder="full name" required>
<input type="text" name="family-member" placeholder="full name"  required>
<input type="text" name="family-member" placeholder="full name"  required>
```

Comment: Retroactively change the names?

Comment: id should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
name="family-member"
```

to

```
name="family-member[]"
```

the post\get array will have a child array with all the "family-member" values